# What are the Tumah implications outside of Temple?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

What are the implication of tumah other than related to the Temple?

E.g., a pathologist in, say, Australia is contaminated with Tumas Mes all the time. Does he have to travel to Jerusalem to get sprinkled with ashes of Parah Aduma after each autopsy? (note that he has to be sprinkled on the 3rd and 7th day!) Or can he continue with his normal life until Nissan?

He has to travel to Jerusalem a *week* before Pesach to be cleansed with ashes of Parah Aduma, right? But if he lives his normal life in tumah, then all his family and property - and, probably, friends as well - are also contaminated. The shul he prays in, the subway he commutes to work in... Basically, it seems that, unless our handling of the dead becomes radically different than it is now, everyone will be tameh unless he takes exceptional precautions. So, does this imply that (other than a small enclave in Jerusalem, dedicated to the tamid services) the whole world would be presumed tameh and everyone who want to bring a korban would have to enter the "buffer enclave" a week before, get cleansed, enter the tahor enclave around the Temple, and then bring the korban?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10976 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/25714

Comment: Are you asking why anyone outside the Temple might need to be pure? What does the rest of your question have to do with that?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Yes, that is the 1st part. The second part is: assuming it is not feasible to be tahor all the time, how the korbanot will be arranged for.