# How to start learning seder taharos

Tags: torah-study, mishna

Would like to start learning mishnayos tahoros with kehati and bartenura, probably at a rate of 2 mishnayos a day. However I've never learned the seder formally so don't know where to start.

I know kelim is probably the logical starting point, but I think it would be tough to gain momentum through the 30 perakim, so I would rather start with something more manageable, like mikvaos or yadayim.

Is there a good starting point that someone could recommend?

Thanks

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10976/can-you-become-more-tamei-if-not-why-do-we-worry-about-it-today#comment54080_10976

Comment: The first chapter of keilim is totally unrelated to the next 29. It's just an intro to the whole Seder

Comment: You will need a picture book. There are a few about one made by Posen of London which is diagrams another called maros chaim. which is pictures. The siyata dishmayo mishnayos also has.

Comment: Might actually be better, rather than jumping into the mishnayos themselves, to start with something like the Rambam's introduction to Seder Taharos (or the Bartenura's, which is a digest of it), or perhaps the Tiferes Yisroel's. All of them are printed at the beginning of the Yachin U'Boaz / Zecher Chanoch Seder Taharos.

Comment: If you are specifically looking to do two mishnayot per day, you might consider the Mishna Yomit (which is really 2 mishnayot daily) shiurim, such as from OU Torah https://www.ou.org/torah/gemara-series/mishna-yomit  Whichever tractate you start with, having someone give a breif shiur can often be helpful.  There are a variety of teachers there, so I assume some will be more to your taste than others.

Answer (score -1):

My Uncle -  a world sought-after Taharos posek -  recommended that I start with Mesechta Taharos.

Comment: It's not such a bad suggestion, since that masechta does deal with a lot of the basic concepts of rishon and sheni and so forth. But it's a bit complex for a beginner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/41134)

Comment: @mbloch how does suggesting a starting point not answer 'Is there a good starting point that someone could recommend?'

Comment: As it stands, it reads more like a comment. We don't know you or your uncle, nor do we understand his justification. If you could [edit] to add his name or his justification, it would be a much better answer. Welcome to the site and hope you will stay learn with us (also note I didn't downvote)